# Problem implementing Threads into an Android App

Tags: java, android, java-threads

I was developing a simple App, in order to practice with Threads into Android Context, an I get an common error, but I don't know why, maybe due to the behavior of the Thread, or I don't know why.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MiHiloLooper looper;
    ImageView iv1, iv2, iv3;
    URL url1, url2, url3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        iv1 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.hilo1);
        iv2 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.hilo2);
        iv3 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        iv3.setImageResource(R.drawable.hilo3);

        try {
            url1 = new URL("https://www.dhresource.com/0x0/f2/albu/g8/M00/E6/A3/rBVaV15BFzGAdY2NAARdO9TdaIk347.jpg/20s-3-1500-yards-length-polyester-thread.jpg");
            url2 = new URL("https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/714bmMviZEL._AC_SY450_.jpg");
            url3 = new URL("https://www.brildor.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/h/p/hps025200.jpg");
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Toast miToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Se ha produido un error al cargar las imagenes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            miToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            miToast.show();
        }

        looper = new MiHiloLooper();
        looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url1, iv1) ));
        looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url2, iv2) ));
        looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url3, iv3) ));



        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            // Lanzammos los hilos con el OnClick del Toolbar.





            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        looper.terminate();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

ImageLoader.class

```
public class ImageLoader implements Runnable {

    ImageView iv;
    URL url;
    Button button;

    public ImageLoader(URL url, ImageView iv){
        this.iv = iv;
        this.url=url;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            final Drawable drawable =
                    Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            button.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("URL","Error downloading image "+
                    url.toString());
        }
    }

}
```

miHiloLooper.class

```
public class MiHiloLooper extends Thread{

    Handler handler; //message handler
    public MiHiloLooper(){
        this.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            Looper.prepare();
            handler = new Handler();
            Looper.loop();
        }catch(Throwable t){
            Log.e("Looper","Error: ", t);
        }
    }
    public void terminate(){
        handler.getLooper().quit();
    }
    public void post(Runnable runnable){
        handler.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

These is the estructure of my App, and the error I get is this:

```
2020-11-21 17:47:11.166 4078-4078/com.example.probandohilos E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.probandohilos, PID: 4078
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.probandohilos/com.example.probandohilos.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.os.Handler.post(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.probandohilos.MiHiloLooper.post(MiHiloLooper.java:27)
        at com.example.probandohilos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I don't understand how I can get a `NullPointerException`, if I've initialized the `Looper` and all the parameters it need.

If you tell me where is the mistake, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `mHandler` is null because the `MiHiloLooper` thread is created synchronously along with posting `Runnable/messages` using its `post` method.

So, when you try to `looper.post()` before the thread creation is over (i.e. before its `run()` is over), then you will face of this NPE.

For illustration purpose, to make your code runs without NPE, you can use `Thread.sleep()` for while to make sure that  `MiHiloLooper` thread is created before posting any runnable to its Looper. Here I am waiting a couple of seconds to make sure that the `looper` thread is created and `mHandler` is not null.

Again it's for illustration purpose, and of course not a production way.

```
looper = new MiHiloLooper();

try {
    Thread.sleep(2000); // delay of 2 sec
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url1, iv1) ));
looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url2, iv2) ));
looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url3, iv3) ));
```

Therefore to solve your problem, you need to run the first line (thread creation) in below code asynchronously with the lines that invoke `post()` method.

```
looper = new MiHiloLooper();
looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url1, iv1) ));
looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url2, iv2) ));
looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url3, iv3) ));
```

You can solve this with a listener interface, that will be triggered whenever your Thread is created.

Here is the new code of your custom Thread, I am passing the listener as constructor parameter; and invoked its callback `onReady()` whenever the handler is initialized, so I am sure that `mHandler` won't be null anymore.

```
public class MiHiloLooper extends Thread{

    Handler handler; //message handler
    
    private CreationListener mCreationListener; // Listener for thread creation

    
    public interface CreationListener {
        void onReady();
    }

    
    public MiHiloLooper(CreationListener listener){ 
        mCreationListener = listener;
        this.start();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            Looper.prepare();
            handler = new Handler();
            mCreationListener.onReady(); // Here I am sure that handler is not null
            Looper.loop();
            
        }catch(Throwable t){
            Log.e("Looper","Error: ", t);
        }
    }
    public void terminate(){
        handler.getLooper().quit();
    }
    public void post(Runnable runnable){
        handler.post(runnable);
    }
}
```

Then in your `MainActivity` add a listener as constructor argument.

```
looper = new MiHiloLooper(new MiHiloLooper.CreationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onReady() {
        looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url1, iv1) ));
        looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url2, iv2) ));
        looper.post(new Thread( new ImageLoader(url3, iv3) ));          
    }
});
```

Aside note: you can add `synchronized` to your `post()` method in order to avoid any race conditions for runnables submitted to `MiHiloLooper` thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Root cause**

When you call [start()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#start()) on a Thread, it does not execute immediately, the system needs to allocate the resources for the thread, then run the code inside [run()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable#run()) method where you initialize the Handler. That explains why you got NPE (NullPointerException) when accessing the Handler right away.

**Solution**

If you want to create a Thread that has a Looper, Android offers you [HandlerThread](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread) API. So change your code to:

*MiHiloLooper.java*

```
class MiHiloLooper extends HandlerThread {

    private Handler handler;

    public MiHiloLooper() {
        this("MiHiloHandlerThread");
    }

    public MiHiloLooper(String name) {
        super(name);
        start();
    }

    public Handler getHandler() {
        if (handler == null) {
            handler = new Handler(getLooper());
        }
        return handler;
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.java*

```
looper = new MiHiloLooper();
looper.getHandler().post(new ImageLoader(url1, iv1));
looper.getHandler().post(new ImageLoader(url2, iv2));
looper.getHandler().post(new ImageLoader(url3, iv3));
```

By the way, there is a line inside *ImageLoader* class

```
button.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
});
```

The `button` variable is not initialized anywhere, so it will crash your app. In this case, you can replace by `iv` variable.

```
iv.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
});
```

Finally, you should not to create a new Thread and pass it to [post()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method of a Handler.

Don't

```
looper.post(new Thread(new ImageLoader(url1, iv1)));
```

Do

```
looper.getHandler().post(new ImageLoader(url1, iv1));
```

Comment: Good to hear that. By the way, if my answer solved your problem then you can mark is as answer. It will help me improving my answers in the future.